# Create Windows 8.1 Store App with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am interested to port one of my windows applications so that I can distribute my app in the Microsoft Store. Target platform will
be Windows 8.1 because I am not running Windows 10.

I am using Visual Studio Community 2017. I tried to follow this guide from Microsoft

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt203664.aspx

to create a Windows 8.1 Store app with Visual Studio but it seems that the described functionality is not available at
Visual Studio Community 2017. Also I cannot find any related Windows Store 8.1 Project Template at Visual Studio Community 2017.

So which is the latest available Visual Studio version which supports creating Windows 8.1. Store Apps?

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8.1 Store app development is not available in Visual Studio 2017. You should use Visual Studio 2015 instead.